# Как переопределить css-класс полей формы авторизации Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Можно ли как-то задать css-классы для полей формы стандартной авторизации?

Я заинклудил urls из модуля auth:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

Теперь по обращению к адресу */auth/login/* у меня срабатывает стандартная вьюха *LoginView*, которая обрабатывает форму *AuthenticationForm*.

Я, конечно, могу создать свою вьюху, унаследованную от LoginView и в нее передать свою форму, унаследованную от AuthenticationForm, например.Но нельзя ли просто как-то добавить классы в стандартную форму? Может быть на уровне шаблона или еще как-то.

Comment: Думаю, нужно переопределять форму.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. В Джанго нет простого пути для этого (во всяком случае, в свое время много потратил на поиски подобного решения, но потерпел фиаско). Можно как вариант стилизовать сами теги формы для этой страницы - это самый простой путь